# method in constructor returns undefined

Tags: javascript, class, oop, constructor

I have a class Squierell. squirell1.jump() method in Squrell returns undefined.no errors in console. Maybe I missed something important in syntax?

```
    class Squirrel {
  constructor(name, color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  set name(name) {
    if (typeof name !== "string") {
      throw TypeError;
    } else {
      this._name = name;
    }
  }
  get color() {
    return this._color;
  }
  set color(color) {
    if (typeof color !== "string") {
      throw TypeError;
    } else {
      return (this._color = color);
    }
  }
  jump() {
    return this._name + " jumping";
  }
}


try {
  const squirell1 = new Squirrel("noname", "red");
  squirell1.jump();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
```

Did I define constructor correctly?

Comment: Please use a debugger and step through the code, set breakpoints and inspect variables. All should become clear then.

Comment: Also, if you have a problem with `squirell1.jump()` as you indicate, why is there all this other code? Please focus on one problem only, and only provide the minimal code needed to produce the problem.